# How do I write a script to keep retrying Yum Update Program?

Tags: unix, yum

My job let me always release a new version of the program to a satellite server, then in the running server, I use `yum update program` to update the program.

However, due to unknown reason, in most of times, even if I upload the program to the satellite server, `yum update program` can't get the update soon. I always have to wait, keep retrying, etc.

So anyone can tell me how to write a script, so

1. it keeps retrying `yum update program` if no update available
2. if update is available, then the update in yum is forced
3. after successful update, the script quits.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data about what's in the repo gets cached.  You should run `yum clean expire-cache` first and then run `yum update` in order to ensure that changes are detected.

Comment: yeah I did that and even more I did `yum clean all`. I dont know what's the problem and I don't care really. I just wish for a script that I can run there to update and I can do something else in the mean while.

Comment: If you're publishing the RPM, why not transfer the rpm to the site directly and simply install it using `rpm -u` or `yum install RPM`?

Comment: I don't know, it is a big company and the company made it in this way.

Comment: Well, somewhere a cache is getting in your way.

Comment: Either on the publication side or the consumption side.  When doing a yum update, I'd watch it carefully to make sure it's pulling the new index file.